# Integrating Spring 2.5 with Ibatis 3

Tags: java, spring, ibatis

Does anyone know of a way to integrate the new Ibatis with the current Spring 2.5? I'm exploring pulling it in to a project and was curious if anyone had done it before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an open JIRA issue for this ([SPR-5991](http://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-5991)). It has iBatis3 support tagged for Spring 3.1

Comment: This is not an easy fix but cuts across a lot of the Spring tx code. I submitted some more code to that issue, but it's by no means production ready. Hopefully it's enough to get people going until Spring officially supports it.

Answer (score 0):

Is it very different from iBatis 2? With Spring 2.5 and iBatis 2 all you had to do was:

```
<bean id="sqlMapClient" class="org.springframework.orm.ibatis.SqlMapClientFactoryBean">
    <property name="configLocation" value="SqlMapConfig.xml" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
```